# Laurent series expansion of $\sqrt{\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}}$ on $1<|z|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I think I can write the function as 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-1/z}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2(1-z/2)}}$$
From here I thought about using the series expansion formula for $(1+x)^{-1/2}$, but then the product of two power series will get complicated. Is there a better way to appoach this problem?

Comment: The problem also says $\text{Im }f(\frac{3}{2}) > 0$ although I'm not sure what that affects.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe the full problem?

Comment: This is the full problem, nothing more than what I wrote down. Where is it not analytic though?

Comment: What does your first comment mean? What is $f$?

Comment: Oh, it just means $f(z) = \sqrt{\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}}$.

Comment: My first comment might be incorrect. I will check when I get a chance. I think it might be the case that $\operatorname{im} {z \over (z-1)(z-2)} < 0$ for all $z $ in the annulus.

Comment: My initial comment was incorrect. It seems that $\operatorname{re} {z \over (z-1)(z-2)} < 0$ for all $z $ in the annulus, so one can use a branch of the logarithm that is defined there and hence $f$ is analytic. Sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a Laurent expansion, but may help:

$f(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{2}} {1 \over \sqrt{(1-{1 \over z}) (1-{z \over 2})}}
=  {1 \over \sqrt{2}} {1 \over \sqrt{{3 \over 2} - ({1 \over z} + {z \over 2})}} =
{1 \over \sqrt{3}} {1 \over \sqrt{1 - {2 \over 3}({1 \over z} + {z \over 2})  }}$.

Let $\phi(t) = {1 \over t} + {t \over 2}$ and note that 
$\max_{t \in [1,2]} \phi(t) = {3 \over 2}$ and that $\phi(t) < {3 \over 2}$
for $t \in (1,2)$.

Hence if $z \in A = \{ w | 1 < |w| <2 \}$, we can use a generalised
binomial expansion:

$f(z) = {1 \over \sqrt{3}} (1 - {2 \over 3}({1 \over z} + {z \over 2})  )^{-{1 \over 2}} = {1 \over \sqrt{3}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-{1 \over 2}}{k} (- {2 \over 3})^k ({1 \over z} + {z \over 2})^k$